# Loading externally partitioned data into BQ tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Avro files in GCS and the path where files are loaded is like -
gs://folder1/folder2/2021/02/23/00/00/file1.avro
gs://folder1/folder2/2021/02/23/00/00/file2.avro
and so on
Numbers in the path is basically year/month/day/hour/minute/file1.avro
Now I want to load this file into table (table is not created in BQ) which I want to create during load operation.
I want to partition the table by Year/month/day. I tried below command -

```
bq load -project_id=projectname \
--clustering_fields=col1,col2 \
--source_format=AVRO --hive_partitioning_mode=CUSTOM \
--hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://source/folder1/{year:integer}/{month:integer}/{day:integer}/ projectname:datasetname.table1 gs://source/folder1//2021/02/23/20/00/*.avro 
col1:INTEGER,col2:INTEGER,col3:INTEGER,col4:STRING,col5:STRING,col6:TIMESTAMP
```

After that I am getting error -
Error in query string: Error processing job 'projectname:bq_job_fdkf2342': Partition keys should be invariant from table creation across all partitions, with the
number of partition keys held constant with invariant names.  Expected 3 partition keys ([year, month, day]), but 0 ([) were encountered for partition 2021/02/23/20/00.

Any help appreciated